# Laravel Multiple Migration Table in one Statement

Tags: php, laravel, web, migration

I am new to Laravel and I'm confused if it is possible to create a multiple migration table in Laravel in just one run? 
Like:

```
php artisan make:migration user_acc_tbl --create=user_acc_tbl, user_info_tbl --create=user_info_tbl, skills_tbl --create=skills_tbl
```

I hope it is possible. So that we can just run the command once from the command terminal to create multiple migration files. It would be really helpful though.

Comment: As @Polaris said with artisan console you can't but if you're on unix just combine the desired migrations to create with `&&` and hit enter, the terminal will automatically return new line and type another migration command as long you type `&&` operator at the end.
Not the best answer but kinda works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Laravel documentation, it is not possible to make multiple migrations in one command line. You may be able to write a custom artisan console command and do it that way, however I really don't see how it would save that much time.

What you could do is create multiple tables from one migration file. Just use Schema::create and create the proper tables with the necessary columns.

You could also create aliases to help speed up workflow in the terminal.